# Understanding C++ reconstruct syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, scope, language-lawyer

Can we call an object's constructor again after it is created?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A ( ) { std::cout << "A::A" << std::endl; }
    ~A ( ) { std::cout << "A::~A" << std::endl; }
};

int main( )
{
    A a;
    a.~A();    // OK
    a.A::A();  // OK in Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can the last call be OK? oO

Comment: The last line is not OK.... http://ideone.com/krhrq

Comment: @jrok, it compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: What on earth are you compiling this on, then?

Comment: You should update your compiler then.

Comment: Before everyone starts switching their upvotes to downvotes. The question still stands without that last call.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Not on g++ 4.6.3 it doesn't. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Mysticial But the title and the Q body should be changed then.

Comment: @Mysticial the question is "why can I explicitly call a constructor using this syntax but not using this one?". But non of them compile, so...

Comment: Hmm, I'm using VC++ 10, but I've seen this syntax (the last call) elsewhere.

Comment: So it the consensus that this only works in Visual C++?

Comment: @Karoly, this was actually part of an interview question on a phone interview.

Comment: Your answer should have been: "this does not work on standard C++".

Comment: I confirmed that the `a.A::A();` line compiles in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 both.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: No, that isn't the consensus, because we haven't checked on all compilers. The consensus seems to be that it _should_ not work on _any_ std-compliant compiler. Informally, however, we all agree that VC is a very likely candidate for a bug like this.

Comment: I was as indigent about this when I first saw it as everyone else here. But take a look at this page, in figure 2 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That's labelled as pseudo-code.

Comment: @GMan, I know, it it _does_ compile.

Comment: @mfontanini, thanks, next time I'll know.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That doesn't mean it's standard. I'm not sure what the question is anymore.

Comment: @GMan, I will edit the question.

Comment: In `a.A()`, the `A` names the struct type `A`. If you say `a.A::A()`, the last `A` names the constructor (this is according to Standard rules). However the Standard forbids to do direct calls to the constructor (actually pretty much anything except a few declaration-like things about the constructor is disallowed).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to call the constructor like this, as a member function call. The reason is (n3242, 12.1/2):

> A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type. Because constructors do not have names, they are
>   never found during name lookup; however an explicit type conversion using the functional notation (5.2.3)
>   will cause a constructor to be called to initialize an object.

If you really really want to call constructor on something what should be an object - and you shouldn't do it unless in very special cases - you can use placement new that calls the constructor:

```
new (&a) A();
```

Comment: And don't forget to destroy the object first!

Comment: "they are never found during name lookup", that is incorrect. If they would never be found during name lookup, you could never define a constructor out-of-class, befriend a constructor or inherit a constructor. They don't have a name, but that does *not* imply that they are never found during name lookup. Constructors are found by using the injected class name and making it refer to the constructor(s) as the name-lookup result.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: that's interesting, but maybe you should write the committee about it, since this is a quotation of the standard. You are right that 3.4.3.1/2 allows, in some contexts, finding the constructor in name lookup; luckily, it doesn't allow it in the id-expression of a member function call.

Comment: _Sigh._ What is it with C++ that makes any answer that cites the standard be appreciated more than all the others? `+1` from me, too, though. `:)`

Answer (score 8):

Well, `a.A()` fails to compile because you simply cannot call a constructor in C++. (You can invoke it indirectly, however through several means.) For the same reason, I think `a.A::A()` *should* not compile.

Comment: Indeed: *Constructors do not have names*. It will never be found in name lookup, so it's impossible to invoke directly.

Comment: @GManNickG they don't have names, but they are found in name lookup. See my comment on jpalecek's answer.